# Как передать переменную из js в php через ссылку методом POST запроса

Tags: php, javascript

Есть набросок на  `js`

```js
function  registerIsPressed () 
{ var b = "Регистрация"; document.getElementById("myinput").value=b; }
```

```html
<body> 
 <a href="" onclick="registerIsPressed ();" id="myinput">Зарегистрироваться</a>
 <?
   $b = $_POST['myinput'];
   echo $b;
 ?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="..\wrapper\scripts\js\basic.js"></script></body>
```

Мне нужно что-бы при клике на ссылку передавалась переменная `b` со значением, взятым из файла `js`

Answer (score 1):

А почему через ссылку методом POST? наверно правильнее через ссылку методом GET.  Пример:

> JS

```
function  registerIsPressed () 
{
 var b = "Регистрация"; 
 window.location.href="http://vash_url.ru?myinput="+b

 }
```

> PHP

```
<?php
 $b = $_GET['myinput'];
   echo $b;
?>
```

> UPD

Для передачи значения из `JS` в  `PHP` так же можете использовать `COOKIE`, т.е в js задать куку и после перезагрузки получить данную куку в `PHP`

Comment: Я хочу что-бы путь к странице был максимально красивым типа `http://mysite/pages/info/autentification` а не `http://mysite/pages/info/autentification?якорь=значение`, не используя htacess

Comment: До того как задать вопрос, хоть прочитали в чём разница POST и GET запроса ?  Если вы хотите передать данные через ссылку (как указали в вопросе) - это называется GET запрос. POST запрос отправляется, например, через форму <form>

Comment: @АндрейГолубев обновил ответ, думаю это вам подойдёт

Comment: Я хочу сделать по этому примеру `<a onclick="LogInSignUpModal('signUp');" class="waves-effect btn grey darken-3">` и `<a onclick="LogInSignUpModal('logIn');" class="waves-effect btn grey darken-3">` с сайта https://csgolounge.com/

Comment: А причём тут параметры ? вам надо просто при определённом click открывать(показывать) определённый скрытый div (popup)

Comment: Мне надо что-бы php проверял: 1) Если существует переменная со значением `$b = 'Регистрация'`  то выдавать страницу Регистрации, 2) Если же нет - выдавать страницу Авторизации. А само значение `$b` передавалось асинхронно без перезагрузки самого сайта в `php` через `js` кликая по ссылке

Comment: Вся глубина проблемы в том, что вы изначально не смогли правильно изложить то что вы хотите.... "передавалось асинхронно без перезагрузки самого сайта" ну в этом вам конечно поможет технология AJAX, думаю используя ajax вы получите желаемый результат

Comment: Не могли бы Вы пример написать, а лучше решение моей проблемы? Буду искренне благодарен

Comment: в интернете полно примеров и учебников , на скорую руку ссылка на видео https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=egdPcuBDPEE